# Adding a CALayer sublayer inside of UIView init

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, quartz-2d, uiwindow

I'm trying to add a CALayer as a sublayer in a UIView subclass, but when I add the sublayer inside the init method I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I add the view to another view or window.

## Init method:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.title = title;
        self.message = message;

        self.alertLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    
        self.layer.cornerRadius = kCORNER_RADIUS;
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
        self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(15, 20);
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;

        self.alertLayer.delegate = self;
        self.alertLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.alertLayer.cornerRadius = kCORNER_RADIUS;

        [self.layer addSublayer:self.alertLayer]; // This line of code seems to cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    }

    return self;
}
```

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is caused after calling `[self.view addSubview:alertView]` inside a view controller or UIWindow.

Comment: What memory management semantic do you use for the `alertLayer` property?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two layers (`self.layer` and `self.alertLayer`) which have the same delegate `self`, this leads to an infinite recursion in internal method `-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]` when added this view (`self`) to the view tree. Therefore you must remove `self.alertLayer.delegate = self;` to avoid crash. If you need to delegate for `alarmLayer` you can create distinct object.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that a UIView could only have one layer referencing it as a delegate.